# How to individually delete a dynamically created paragraph?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, paragraph

I have a button that creates paragraphs dynamically in a div along with an ID.
When you create a paragraph you can also select that paragraph ("background color changes") by clicking it, along with that ("When you click on paragraph") a div is created with a link inside of it.
Tried to remove individually but it would remove all the paragraphs at once

How can I remove a paragraph that is being selected("I mean individually")?

Here is link and what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/RzvV5/88/

Javascript/jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = 1;
    $("#push").on({
        click: function(){
            var pr = $('<p class="test">This is text ' + id + '</p>');
            var d = $("#Test");
            var pclone = $(pr).clone();
            pclone.on({
                mouseenter: function(){    
                    $(this).addClass("inside");
                },
                mouseleave: function(){                             
                    $(this).removeClass("inside"); 
                },
            });
            pclone.appendTo(d);
            id++;
        }
    });

    var div =  $('<div class="customD" id="d"></div>');
    var del = $('<a href="#" class="delete" id="erase">Delete</a>');
    var pcust = $(div).clone();
    var pdel = $(del).clone();

    $("#Test").on("click", "p", function(){ 
        var cur = $(this).css("background-color");

        if(cur=="rgb(255, 255, 255)") {  
            $(this).css("background-color","red").addClass("help insider");
            $(this).after(pcust);
        } 
        else { 
            $(this).css("background-color","white").removeClass('help insider');
            $(pcust).remove();
        }    

        $(pcust).append(pdel);

    }); 
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="push">Push</a>
    <div id="Test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.test { color: #000; padding: .5em; margin: 0px; border: 2px solid white; background: white;} 

.help { border: 2px dashed #FDD }

.inside { border: 2px solid red    }

.insider { border: 2px solid #FDD; }

.delete {  font-size: 12px; }
.customD { background: yellow}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add click event handler to delete link

```
 $(".delete").live("click",function(){
        $(this).parent().prev().remove();
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

BTW. You don't have to clone each time link and its parent div, you can build up that part of dome and hold same reference, if you reuse it with

```
var div =  $('<div class="customD" id="d"></div>');
var del = $('<a href="#" class="delete" id="erase">Delete</a>');
div.append(del);

    $("#Test").on("click", "p", function(){ 

       ....
       $(pcust).append(del); //this will not clone delete div, it will actually replace its position it dome structure and move it from one paragraph to "pcust". This will save memory!!!

        ....
    };
```